Java script code to swap solana coin on Orca
I met issues with Solana trading bot development.
I plan to exchange Solana coins using the Orca platform and are using the Whirlpool SDK.
This is my current code. But this only works once out of 10 attempts.
And display error message like this.
*D:\orcaswap\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:3957
        throw new TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError(signature);
              ^
TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError: Signature 5ZwCXRZCJXDq295sEaDZ2SHQpuyct1dj1JLFRRKrbhX9DEhwbRQWJmwPR848axpSgkgsQqN4TXnZfLEEaR77wdgP has expired: block height exceeded.
    at Connection.confirmTransactionUsingBlockHeightExceedanceStrategy (D:\orcaswap\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:3957:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.confirmTransaction (D:\orcaswap\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\src\connection.ts:3768:14)
    at async TransactionBuilder.buildAndExecute (D:\orcaswap\node_modules\@orca-so\common-sdk\dist\web3\transactions\transactions-builder.js:246:24) {
  signature: '5ZwCXRZCJXDq295sEaDZ2SHQpuyct1dj1JLFRRKrbhX9DEhwbRQWJmwPR848axpSgkgsQqN4TXnZfLEEaR77wdgP'
}*

Please help me if you know what error is in my code or if you have the correct code.
thank you.
**import { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey, Transaction } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { Wallet } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { IGNORE_CACHE, ORCA_WHIRLPOOL_PROGRAM_ID, PDAUtil, WhirlpoolContext, buildWhirlpoolClient, swapQuoteByInputToken } from "@orca-so/whirlpools-sdk";
import { Decimal } from "decimal.js";
import { DecimalUtil, Percentage } from "@orca-so/common-sdk";
const swap = async () => {
    const connection = new Connection(
        "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
    );
    const wallet = new Wallet(
        Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(...)),
    );
    const ctx = WhirlpoolContext.from(
        connection,
        wallet,
        ORCA_WHIRLPOOL_PROGRAM_ID,
    );
    const devSOL = { mint: new PublicKey("So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"), decimals: 9 };
    const devUSDC = { mint: new PublicKey("EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v"), decimals: 6 };
    const whirlpoolClient = buildWhirlpoolClient(ctx);
    const DEVNET_WHIRLPOOLS_CONFIG = new PublicKey("2LecshUwdy9xi7meFgHtFJQNSKk4KdTrcpvaB56dP2NQ");
    const tick_spacing = 64;
    const whirlpool_pubkey = PDAUtil.getWhirlpool(
        ORCA_WHIRLPOOL_PROGRAM_ID,
        DEVNET_WHIRLPOOLS_CONFIG,
        devSOL.mint, devUSDC.mint, tick_spacing).publicKey;
    const whirlpool = await whirlpoolClient.getPool(whirlpool_pubkey);
    const amountIn = new Decimal("1" /* devSOL */);
    const quote = await swapQuoteByInputToken(
        whirlpool,
        // Input token and amount
        devSOL.mint,
        DecimalUtil.toBN(amountIn, devSOL.decimals),
        // Acceptable slippage (10/1000 = 1%)
        Percentage.fromFraction(50, 1000),
        ctx.program.programId,
        ctx.fetcher,
        IGNORE_CACHE,
    );
    console.log("estimatedAmountIn:", DecimalUtil.fromBN(quote.estimatedAmountIn, devSOL.decimals).toString(), "devSOL");
    console.log("estimatedAmountOut:", DecimalUtil.fromBN(quote.estimatedAmountOut, devUSDC.decimals).toString(), "devUSDC");
    console.log("otherAmountThreshold:", DecimalUtil.fromBN(quote.otherAmountThreshold, devUSDC.decimals).toString(), "devUSDC");
    // Send the transaction
    const tx = await whirlpool.swap(quote);
    const signature = await tx.buildAndExecute();
    console.log("signature:", signature);
    // Wait for the transaction to complete
    const latest_blockhash = await ctx.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    const txId = await ctx.connection.confirmTransaction({ signature, ...latest_blockhash }, "confirmed");
    return {
        txId,
    };
}
swap();


Does this answer your question? How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?
